# How to align the ads with the menu?

Tags: html, css

I am working on [a website](http://www.apptec.net/) where I have to add ads below the menu but they should be aligned with the menu from the left. I tried to apply padding to the ads but its causing a problem when I increase or decrease the size of the page(`CTRL+` or `CTRL-`). Is there a way I can align it with the menu and keep it aligned for all browsers?

Thanks in advance.
Here is what I did,

```
ads{
padding-left:170px;
}
```

Comment: I just don't see why div.ads isn't enclosed by div.content.

Comment: @Pankaj: Just below the menu with the same padding as the menu.

Comment: apply content class to that div.

Comment: @Pankaj: I did it but it did not worked.

Comment: it worked fine let me show you the screenshot.

Comment: your whole site is not wrapped in any particular parent div

Comment: are you doing changes? its getting weird

Comment: $('.ads'); returns null! You shouldn't change http://www.apptec.net/ as long as you don't have a solution.

Comment: @Pankaj: I was trying out the solutions provided. Sorry.

Comment: @Pankaj: thanks it worked. If you can post it as an answer I can mark it right. thanks

Comment: @Pankaj: Post it below in the answers area so I can mark it as the right answer. It would be good for your reputation.

Comment: hahah akito thanks for your concern :) I did.

Comment: @Pankaj: Also, I would be very thankful if you can help fix the padding issue from the top. If you see the padding from the top, its different from the padding of the menu items.

Comment: you want padding top for ads?

Comment: Yes, the same padding as in between the menu items.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9833/discussion-between-pankaj-and-akito)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay as you have changed your code, apply this css on the outline div.

```
#header .outline {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    z-index: 15;
```

Answer (score 1):

use the position attribute by making the menu relative and the ads absolute

```
#menu{
 position:relative;
 width:80%;
 left:10%;
}
#ads{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 width:80%;
 left:10%;
}
```

with this code how ever you edit your browser's zoom it will be together :)
hope it was helpful, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<style type="text/css">
ads
{
float:right;
}
</style>
```

hope this will help you.